# Need to connect React.js login form to SpringBoot app back end and MySQL database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot

I am new at programming and I am building a full stack app where the front end is a React.js app called 'loginform' where a user can register for an account and afterwards they can login using their credentials and the back end should be SpringBoot and MySQL database to store the new user info and once the user logs in they will be directed to the home page (that I'm building too). But I have been searching far and wide to find a solution to build the back end and connect it to the React front end and I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's what I have so far (and I can supply more of the React code if needed):

ReactJs App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import RegistrationForm from './components/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import PrivateRoute from './utils/PrivateRoute';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AlertComponent from './components/AlertComponent/AlertComponent';

function App() {
  const [title, updateTitle] = useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, updateErrorMessage] = useState(null);

  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" components={LoginForm} />
      <div className="App">
        <Header title={title} />
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact={true}>
              <RegistrationForm showError={updateErrorMessage} updateTitle={updateTitle} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/register">
              <RegistrationForm showError={updateErrorMessage} updateTitle={updateTitle} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
              <LoginForm showError={updateErrorMessage} updateTitle={updateTitle} />
            </Route>
            <PrivateRoute path="/home">
              <Home />
            </PrivateRoute>
          </Switch>
          <AlertComponent errorMessage={errorMessage} hideError={updateErrorMessage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LoginForm.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './LoginForm.css';
import { API_BASE_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME } from '../../constants/apiConstants';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";


function LoginForm(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
        successMessage: null
    })
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { id, value } = e.target
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [id]: value
        }))
    }

    const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const payload = {
            "email": state.email,
            "password": state.password,
        }
        axios.post(API_BASE_URL + 'login', payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.code === 200) {
                    setState(prevState => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        'successMessage': 'Login successful. Redirecting to home page..'
                    }))
                    localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME, response.data.token);
                    redirectToHome();
                    props.showError(null)
                }
                else if (response.data.code === 204) {
                    props.showError("Username and password do not match");
                }
                else {
                    props.showError("Username does not exist");
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    const redirectToHome = () => {
        props.updateTitle('Home')
        props.history.push('/home');
    }
    const redirectToRegister = () => {
        props.history.push('/register');
        props.updateTitle('Register for TEAMBOX');
    }
    return (
        <div className="card col-12 col-lg-4 login-card mt-2 hv-center">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group text-center"></div>
                <img src="/Teamboxwhite.png" alt="" />
                <div className="form-group text-left">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="email"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        value={state.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <medium id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">Please enter your email to login.</medium>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group text-left">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={state.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                </div>
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={handleSubmitClick}
                >Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div className="alert alert-success mt-2" style={{ display: state.successMessage ? 'block' : 'none' }} role="alert">
                {state.successMessage}
            </div>
            <div className="registerMessage">
                <span>Don't have an account? </span>
                <span className="loginText" onClick={() => redirectToRegister()}>Register</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

I know it's a lot to review, but any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's way too much to review. Can you trim this down to code *specifically* relevant to the problem?

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with asking for that, it's off-topic here because it's just too broad a subject. That's more something you'd use [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io) to pair up with someone to solve.